# Specifying an array to be sent as a GET parameter using Swagger/OpenAPI spec

Tags: php, rest, http, swagger, openapi

The following swagger definition:

```
swagger: '2.0'
host: example.com
paths:
  /theResource:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/fields'
parameters:
  fields:
    name: fields
    description: Fields to return
    in: query
    type: array
    collectionFormat: multi
    uniqueItems: true
    items:
      type: string
      enum:
        - column1
        - column2
        - column3
```

Will generate the following URL, and the server will only receive `fields` equal to `column3`.

```
http://example.com/theResource?fields=column1&fields=column2&fields=column3
```

How do I change it so that it sends an array in the parameter?  For instance:

```
http://example.com/theResource?fields[]=column1&fields[]=column2&fields[]=column3
```

Comment: Maybe just change the name from `fields` to `fields[]`?

Comment: By the way, the term you're looking for is YAML (not swagger - swagger is the product)

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Yes, it is YAML, but it could also be JSON.  Maybe I should have said "Open API specification"?

Comment: No. It's YAML (definately not JSON).

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ  I showed definitely YAML format, but could have expressed the Open API spec (i.e Swagger spec) in JSON just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/http_build_query), that will construct proper query part of URL for you.

```
<?php

$query = http_build_query([
    'fields' => [
        'one', 'two', 'three'
    ],
]);

$url = "https://example.com/?".$query;
```

And yes, the `fields[]` syntax should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej, however, I know how to do so using PHP, but wish to do so using the Swagger/OpenAPI spec.